# Processor implementation

Tags: riscv

Can you help me about the code below.
Is it writing 1 to the data memory or to the internal memory.
there are only 32 internal registers
The processor is 32 bit risc-v based
thanks in advance

```
#include "string.h"
#define DEBUG_IF_ADDR 0x00002010

    void bubble_sort(int* arr, int len)
    {
        int sort_num;
        do
        {
            sort_num = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<len-1;i++)
            {
                if(*(arr+i) > *(arr+i+1))
                {
                    int tmp = *(arr+i);
                    *(arr+i) = *(arr+i+1);
                    *(arr+i+1) = tmp;
                    sort_num++;
                }
            } 
        }
        while(sort_num!=0);
    }
    
    int main() 
    {
        int unsorted_arr[] = {195,14,176,103,54,32,128};
        int sorted_arr[] = {14,32,54,103,128,176,195};
        bubble_sort(unsorted_arr,7);
    
        int *addr_ptr = DEBUG_IF_ADDR;
        if(memcmp((char*) sorted_arr, (char*) unsorted_arr, 28) == 0)
        {
            //success
            *addr_ptr = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            //failure
            *addr_ptr = 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How is this about either "Processor implementation" or "RISC V""?  It's just some C code.  (The only thing even potentially close to either of those is the hard coded memory address.)

Comment: Are you expecting something other than `main`s  then-part writing 1? If so, what and why?